# Integration of Angular website with SAML (SSO)

Tags: python, angularjs, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I have a website with frontend in AngularJS and backend in Python.

Currently we are presenting the user with a simple webform to fetch credentials.

The credentials from the form are sent to the Python backend(`flask` webservice)(this is a basic auth mechanism).

Now we would like to enable Single Sign on (`SSO`) on the website.Our identity provider is `Pingone` or `Ping Federate`.

I am starting from scratch here..with no prior knowledge of `SAML` or `SSO`.
I would like to know which path to take?

Which libraries to use and more importantly,how to use them?
At this point in time I am not sure how exactly `SAML` identifies a user and then authenticates him/her.

Answer (score 3):

The basic exchange of SAML starts with a user asking for a resources (page, SPA app) on your Python server.  The server determines if the user is already authenticated (has a session, JWT token, etc), and if not, creates a SAML request token to be sent via a redirect to the Identity Provider (use a library for this).

The identity provider verifies the SAML request token via digital signature. Once the token is verified, the user is asked to log in (if they are not already authenticated there).  Once the user is authenticated, the identity provider creates a SAML request token which is presented back at your server via a redirect.

Upon receipt of the SAML request token, your server validates the token via digital signature, and you treat the user as logged in (again, use a library for this part).  The token will minimally identify the user, but can contain authorizations and additional info. At this point your user is authenticated and you would create a session on your server or you create a JWT token to identify your user from within your angular app to the Python backend.

Creating the SAML request token and processing in the resultant SAML response token is not trivial.  As suggested above, use a library, preferably one that has been through the the test of time.  I'm not a Python dev, but I found this with some googling: [onelogin/python-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0) has a nice sequence diagram to demonstrate this and of course you can peruse the many docs on the [Oasis SAML docs website](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0.html).

Good luck with the implementation.  I've done it a couple times in Java.